# Passing the correct file based on the string ouput

Tags: java

I have the following code which merges two audio files into one:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;

public class WavAppender {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String wavFile1 = "D:\\wav1.wav";
        String wavFile2 = "D:\\wav2.wav";

        try {
            AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile1));
            AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile2));

            AudioInputStream appendedFiles = 
                            new AudioInputStream(
                                new SequenceInputStream(clip1, clip2),     
                                clip1.getFormat(), 
                                clip1.getFrameLength() + clip2.getFrameLength());

            AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles, 
                            AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, 
                            new File("D:\\wavAppended.wav"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I will have a string in the following format [1,2,3,4,5]. Based on the string I will need to select the appropriate wav file. For example if the string is in the format [3,4,5,6,7], I will need to send wavfile 3, wavfile4, wavfile5, wavfile6 and wavfile 7. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array or `List` of items, so that wavfile1 is at index 0, wavfile2 is at index 1 and so on and so forth.

Take each element from the `String` array and convert to to `int`, subtract one from it (as arrays and lists are zero indexed) and that becomes your index for the "wave file array"...

```
String waveFile = waveFiles[Integer.parseInt(indicies[0]) - 1];
```

...Now this prone to some issues, particularly the conversion of the `String` to `int`...

Instead, you could use a `Map` instead, where each wave file is mapped to the corresponding `String` id

```
Map<String, String> waveFiles = new ...;
waveFiles.put("1", "WaveFile1");
waveFiles.put("2", "WaveFile2");
//...
```

Then you would simply use the value from the `String` array to look it up...

```
String waveFile = waveFiles.get(indicies[0]);
```

As some ideas...

Take a look at the [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details and ideas...

Comment: Isn't that what the second example (`Map`) is?